# Execute Sql migration files from archive

Tags: flyway

I'm using Flyway 3.2.1 from Ant with only Sql file migration file and I want to archive these migration files into one zip or jar.

Anyway to execute migrate or validate from an archive instead from a directory ?

My config:

```
<flyway:validate>
  <locations>
    <location path="filesystem:c:\my-migration-folder-root" />
  </locations>
</flyway:validate>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's described literally on the Flyway Ant tasks page: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/ant/

Set `flyway.classpath` to include the jar and you should be OK.